# File containing the current public IP address: why sometimes empty?

Tags: nslookup

I am still a beginner in script writing with no educational backgroud in this direction (I studied math, but seldom programmed). I just do it for personal necessity, like monitoring things.

I wanted to use dynamic dns since fixed IP is expensive, but my router is double-NAT (OpenWRT behind a fritzbox as a modem router), so I cannot get the public IP using ifconfig. I was using kdig, but then was told that kdig takes a lot of memory or cpu and that might be causing crash of another program. Someone suggested my to use nslookup instead.

So I tried the following:

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | grep -m2 "Address" | tail -n1 | awk  '{print $2}' > /tmp/currentip  


if [ ! -s /tmp/currentip ]; # if currentip does not have more than 0 size (i.e. is 0 size)
then
  cp /tmp/oldip /tmp/currentip
else
  STATUS=$(cmp -s /tmp/currentip /tmp/oldip; echo $?)  

     if [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]]; then  # if status isn't equal to 0, then execute code
     cat /tmp/currentip | msmtp xxxxxxx@gmail.com 
     cp /tmp/currentip /tmp/oldip

    fi
fi
```

The commented-out lines are just for myself to understand what I am doing. The file "currentip" is then used for dynamic DNS as the source of the current public IP. When the IP changes, I get an email with it.

Now, as you see, I set it up so that in case nslookup might fail, yealding an empty content, the file `currentip` should stay just the same as before in the end, instead of remaining empty.

This script is then executed by cron for every minute. (in OpenWRT: the current version)

However, I get about 4-5 times a day an email with an empty content, immediately followed by another one with the address which is just the same as before. But I thought I excluded that possibility. Could anyone possibly tell me why it's happening? What did I do wrong? It looks like `[ ! -s /tmp/currentip ]`  is not working properly, but I don't know why....
I will appreciate your help!

Comment: For diagnostic reasons, I recommend to also persist the pure nslookup output into a file, and the output after the first pipe, the output after the second pipe etc. Then in case of getting no ip, reading those files you hopefully will be better understanding where the things went wrong

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! Now I am going to replace one line starting nslookup with

Comment: nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com > /tmp/currentnslookup
if [ ! -s /tmp/currentnslookup ]; then
  grep -m2 "Address" /tmp/currentnslookup > currentgrepm2
else 
  mv /tmp/currentnslookup /tmp/nslookupempty
  touch /tmp/currentgrepm2
fi 
if [ ! -s /tmp/currentgrepm2 ]; then
   tail -n1 /tmp/currentgrepm2 > /tmp/currenttailn1
else 
   mv /tmp/currentgrepm2 /tmp/grepm2empty
   touch /tmp/currenttailn1
fi
if [ ! -s /tmp/currenttailn1 ]; then
awk  '{print $2}' /tmp/currenttailn1 > /tmp/currentip
else 
  mv /tmp/currenttailn1 /tmp/tailn1empty
  touch /tmp/currentip fi

Comment: Then when I get an empty email, I will see at which stage it went empty by looking for a file named xxxempty. I guess that's what you meant ? Sorry for bad-looking posting. It looks like, to answer to a comment, but then I can't make the code look better. Sorry, I have never posted to stackoverflow....

Comment: Sorry, I meant all without "!" I couldn't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: Now, as I replaced the line with many pipes with many lines without a pipe, I suddenly stopped getting any mail with an empty content as I described in the question. But the script is working: I checked it by deleting /tmp/oldip, then I did get an email with the IP address. Does using a lot of pipes cause problems ?

Comment: One thing you could do is to make a web request to one of those free sites that print your ip address - such as for instance https://www.whatismyip.com/ - and then just filter the output.

For instance on that site, open it in Mozilla Firefox, then select "More Tools" / "Web Developer Tools" from the menu.  In the bottom pane that opens, click that little arrow thing to the left of "Inspector", then click on where your ip address is displayed on the page.  It will show you where in the HTML code that's located.  They might not like you polling them too often, though ...

Answer (score 0):

this code looks fine , suggested modification

```
ipinf = $(nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | grep -m2 "Address" | tail -n1 | awk  '{print $2}')
echo $ipinf  > /tmp/currentip
echo $ipinf date > /tmp/saveipinfo
```

When you run it for a day and the problem you mentioned occurs again, you can check it to know what you found

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Only, I'm too inexperienced in this, I can't tell where your line is supposed to break: I'm guessing, echo is the beginning of a new line ? 

And, when the problem arises, where should I look? 

Right now, with the modification mentioned above, I get this problem a few times in 2 weeks or so: and this "a few times" is within a certain short time interval. Then it doesn't happen again for a long time. I wonder if OpenWRT is hanged up or something.

Comment: My suggestion above basically means that every time the IP information is obtained, it must be timestamped and saved in a file. Anyway the string data is not very big. Then run for a period of time, when there is a problem, you can query the contents of the saved file, and you will know what you found

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone is interested in this topic anymore. I found the solution to my question just now. My script was alright, and my router was also fine. It was `myip.opendns.com` that was at fault. Usually

```
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

spits out

```
Server:     resolver1.opendns.com
Address:    208.67.222.222:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   myip.opendns.com
Address: 84.135.xxx.xxx

Non-authoritative answer:
```

as the output (the address with xxx.xxx is mine). I do then

```
| grep -m2 "Address" | tail -n1 | awk  '{print $2}' > /tmp/currentip
```

Then the file `currentip` just contains my address. But then, when `myip.opendns.com` doesn't do the job, it spits out

```
Server:     resolver1.opendns.com
Address:    208.67.222.222:53

Non-authoritative answer:

*** Can't find myip.opendns.com: No answer
```

So my `currentip` file is going to contain 208.67.222.222:53 instead of my IP address. Now, what's interesting is, when I then do

```
cat /tmp/currentip | msmtp xxxx@gmail.com
```

I get an empty email. And the culprit is `:`. I created a short text containing `:` , then msmtp sends an empty email.
So that was the reason why I was getting an empty email, followed by an email containing the IP address, which hasn't changed.
I was worried that something might be very wrong with my router, but thank goodness, that isn't the case! Thank you all for your suggestions. Making the one-line command with pipes into steps helped in figuring out what happened.